# Using Angular to iterate through a JSON and get the result

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have this following JSON format:

```
[{
"-KQVfnf1ZCml7dZ1dZAC": {
    "content": {
        "data": "New Order",
        "type": "text/plain"
    },
    "conversation_id": "990",
    "is_admin": false,
    "is_announce": false,
    "is_deleted": false,
    "message_id": "9694",
    "sender": {
        "name": "Paras",
        "user_id": "285"
    },
    "sent_at": "1472648381032"
},
"-KQVgEHps9L3l80nmkWb": {
    "content": {
        "data": "New Shipment",
        "type": "text/plain"
    },
    "conversation_id": "990",
    "is_admin": false,
    "is_announce": false,
    "is_deleted": false,
    "message_id": "9694",
    "sender": {
        "name": "Paras",
        "user_id": "285"
    },
    "sent_at": "1472648431073"
},
"created_at": "1472647272113",
"$id": "messages",
"$priority": null
```

}]

Now I am using Angular to retrieve the part of the data that I need from the JSON Array.

The Angular Code is:

```
$scope.user_message = [];
   $scope.user_content = [];
   angular.forEach($scope.messages, function(value, key){
     $scope.user_message.push(value);
     angular.forEach($scope.user_message, function(value, key){
       $scope.user_content.push(value[key]);
       console.log($scope.user_content);
     });
   });
```

The Data that I want to retrieve from the JSON is:

```
{
"content": {
    "data": "New Order",
    "type": "text/plain"
},
"conversation_id": "990",
"is_admin": false,
"is_announce": false,
"is_deleted": false,
"message_id": "9694",
"sender": {
    "name": "Paras",
    "user_id": "285"
},
"sent_at": "1472648381032"
```

}

So, basically I want everything from the JSON Array except the message id key that starts with -KQV...

But it is always returning Key: 0 Value: [object Object].

Can anyone help me out with a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Object.keys(object).foreach()` syntax to iterate through each key of the object and check if the object name begins with `-KQV`.  If so, use that object.  That will get you the specific part of each array that you want.  Here, I'm printing it to the console and pushing it into the `$scope.user_message` array.

```
$scope.user_message = [];
for (var i=0; i < $scope.messages.length; i++) {
    Object.keys($scope.messages[i]).forEach(function(key,index) {
        if (key.substr(0, 4) == '-KQV') {
            console.log($scope.messages[i][key]);
            $scope.user_message.push($scope.messages[i][key]);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is shorter but assumes that the first element of the JSON array always contains the messages:

```
//var j = JSON.parse(...)
for (key in j[0]) {
  if (j[0].hasOwnProperty(key) && (key != "created_at") && (key != "$id") && (key != "$priority")) {
    console.log(j[0][key]);
  }
}
```

It also blacklists out the keys that we are sure are not messages ('created_at', etc.), instead of whitelisting those that begin with a specific string ('-Kv'), which might change eventually.

Comment: Thanks for the share. I will keep this snippet handy with your conditions in mind. As, of now, going with Dr. Cool's code. Still Upvote to you.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are after, it would be nice if you can expand your messages array with more sample messages and provide an expected output. This version of your code will stash all of the objects in each message into $scope.user_content (it has no checks for 'KQV'):

```
$scope.user_message = [];
   $scope.user_content = [];
   angular.forEach($scope.messages, function(value, key){
     $scope.user_message.push(value);
     angular.forEach(value, function(value1, key1){
       if (value1 === null || typeof value1 !== 'object') return;
       $scope.user_content.push(value1);

     });
   });
 console.log($scope.user_content);
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/b2gy2yr1/

I would also recommend looking into lodash - it makes this sort of tasks a lot easier:
https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0

Comment: Thanks for the help. Will take your advice and try out lodash in the near future.